# Создать двумерный массив, связать его с таблицей состоящей из инпутов с возможностью добавления/удаления столбцов и строк на JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать двумерный массив на js, связать его с таблицей, которая состоит из инпутов, данная таблица должная иметь возможность добавления/удаления строк и столбцов при нажатии на определенную кнопку, может у кого есть примеры или просто подскажете как делать, я в этом новенький.

Получилось пока, что только это, я не знаю или вообще это правильно:

**JS:**

```
    window.onload = function () {

    let get = function (id) {

        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function create_table(arrayRows, arrayColumns)
    {
        let array = [];

        let table = document.getElementById ('tableContainer');

        for (let i = 0; i < arrayRows; i++)
        {
            array[i] = [];

            let row =  table.insertRow(-1);

            for (let j = 0; j < arrayColumns; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = i + j;

                let cell = row.insertCell(-1);

                cell.innerHTML ="<input>";
            }
        }
        get("addRows").onclick = function()
        {

        }

        get("delRows").onclick = function()
        {

        }

        get("addColumns").onclick = function()
        {

        }

        get("delColumns").onclick = function ()
        {

        }
    }
    create_table(2, 2);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <table id="tableContainer" style="margin-top:20px;"></table>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <input id="addRows" type="button" value="+ строка">
    <input id="delRows" type="button" value="- строка"/>
    <input id="addColumns" type="button" value="+ колонка"/>
    <input id="delColumns" type="button" value="- колонка"/>
</div>
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привожу пример работы функции добавления/удаления строк/ячеек

```js
let array = [];
let table = document.getElementById('tableContainer');   
let rows, columns;

window.onload = function () {
  let get = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }
  function create_table(arrayRows, arrayColumns) {
    [rows, columns] = [arrayRows, arrayColumns];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayRows; i++) {
      array[i] = [];
      let row =  table.insertRow(-1);
      for (let j = 0; j < arrayColumns; j++) {
        array[i][j] = i + j;
        let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML ="<input>";
      }
    }
    get("addRows").onclick = function() {
      let row = table.insertRow(-1);
      array[rows] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        array[rows][j] = rows + j;
        let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML ="<input>";
      }
      rows++;
    }
    get("delRows").onclick = function() {
      if (rows < 1) return;
      rows--;
      array.splice(rows, 1); //убираем строку из массива
      [...table.querySelectorAll("tr")].pop().remove(); //удаляем последнюю строку таблицы
    }
    get("addColumns").onclick = function() {
      let tr = [...table.querySelectorAll("tr")]; //получаем все строки таблицы
      array.forEach((r,i)=>{ //проходим по всем строкам в массиве
        r[r.length] = i + r.length;
        let cell = tr[i].insertCell(-1); //добавляем ячейку в текущую строку
        cell.innerHTML ="<input>";
      });
      columns++;
    }
    get("delColumns").onclick = function (){
      if (columns < 1) return;
      columns--;
      let tr = [...table.querySelectorAll("tr")];
      array.forEach((r,i)=>{
        r.splice(columns,1);
        [...tr[i].querySelectorAll("td")].pop().remove(); //удаляем ячейки
      });
    }
  }
  create_table(2, 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <table id="tableContainer" style="margin-top:20px;"></table>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <input id="addRows" type="button" value="+ строка">
    <input id="delRows" type="button" value="- строка"/>
    <input id="addColumns" type="button" value="+ колонка"/>
    <input id="delColumns" type="button" value="- колонка"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.